# Can't emit from server to client and from client to server [Socket.io]

Tags: socket.io

I'm creating my product and stuck with this problem. One day I setuped socket.io and everything worked well. On the next day I migrate my server and client from http to https. After the migration client side and server side still connected, but I can't emit from client side to server and from server to client.

#### Server side

I have my ssl certificate inside `./security/cert.key` and `./security/cert.pem` they are loading correctly. My server running on `https://localhost:5000`

```js
import fs from "fs";
import https from "https";
import socketio from "socket.io";
import express from "express";

// HTTPS optiosn
const httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("./security/cert.key"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("./security/cert.pem"),
};

// Setup express and https server
const app = express();
const server = https.createServer(httpsOptions, app);

// Setup socket io
const io = socketio.listen(server, {
    origins: "https://localhost:3000",
    transports: ["websocket"],
});

server.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log(`server listening on https://localhost:5000`);
});


io.listen(server);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("new socket connected!");
    console.log(`data = ${socket.handshake.query.data}`);
    socket.emit("some-event");
    socket.on("some-event-2", () => console.log("some-event-2 happened!"));
});
```

#### Client Side

My example react component. My react app is running on `https://localhost:3000`. HTTPS is connected and working well.

```js
import React from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";

const Sandbox: React.FC = () => {
    const query = {
        "data": 123,
    };
    const socket = io.connect("https://localhost:5000", {
        secure: true,
        query,
        transports: ["websocket"],
    });
    socket.on("connect", () => console.log("connect!"));
    socket.on("some-event", () => console.log("some event happened"));
    socket.emit("some-event-2");
    return <React.Fragment />;
};


export default Sandbox;
```

And now the problem. On client side in console I should see `connect!` and `some event happened`
And on server side I should see the messages `new socket connected!` and `data = 123`, `some-event-2 happened!`. But instead my client side console is completely clear[image: Client side console log]

And server side console have only a few logs, but dont contains emit logs
[image: Server side console log]

What should I do? Maybe I'm incorrectly using socket.io with `https`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my error.

The problem was that I was firstly create https server and after that only call `.listen()` on it. `listen()` - is not a void, it's return another server obj. You need to pass the result of `.listen()` function inside your `io.listen()`

```js
// Don't do that❌
var server = https.createServer(options, app);
server.listen(5000);
io.listen(server);

// Do that✅
var server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(5000);
io.listen(server);
```